# How to get user feed from linkedin api

Tags: linkedin-api

With facebook you can easily get a user's feed with the following link.

v2.4/{user-id}/feed.

And it works just fine.

However im unable to find anything of that sort in linkedin api documentation.

Can somebody point me as to how can i do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn does not currently provide such a feed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a node library for this.

try this ->[Node Library](https://github.com/ArkeologeN/node-linkedin)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some hidden documentation related to this, I chanced upon it while doing a google search looking for the same documentation as you. I have never tried it so I do not know if it works.

I dropped them a message asking about it but they have yet to respond.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/activity-feed